# Issue with __nextSuper

Tags: ember.js

Moving from Ember 1.5.1 to 1.6.0, I've run into an issue with `__nextSuper` (which has been changing in the last few versions). You can see the offending code [here](https://github.com/gordonkristan/ember-graph/blob/20bffc3487f54ebda1787746f95c74b605f69a58/src/model/attribute.js#L220).

And here's the relevant Ember code:

```
function wrap(func, superFunc) {
  function superWrapper() {
    var ret, sup = this.__nextSuper; // THIS LINE
    this.__nextSuper = superFunc;
    ret = apply(this, func, arguments);
    this.__nextSuper = sup;
    return ret;
  }

  superWrapper.wrappedFunction = func;
  superWrapper.wrappedFunction.__ember_arity__ = func.length;
  superWrapper.__ember_observes__ = func.__ember_observes__;
  superWrapper.__ember_observesBefore__ = func.__ember_observesBefore__;
  superWrapper.__ember_listens__ = func.__ember_listens__;

  return superWrapper;
};
```

What happens is, at some point, the `superWrapper` function gets called with `window` as the `this` value. So when I reach the line marked above, `this.__nextSuper` comes out to be `undefined`. But rather than `sup` simply being undefined, it throws the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '__nextSuper' of undefined
```

The thing is, when I pause in the debugger, `this` *is* defined (it's the window object). And when I paste `var ret, sup = this.__nextSuper;` into the console, it works as expected. And, if I go up the stack frame and check the `this` value, it's exactly what I expect. So I have no idea why `superWrapper` suddenly has a bad `this` value.

Finally, the most interesting part, this only happens in the browser; it works fine in PhantomJS. The changelog didn't seem to list anything to do with `__nextSuper` as a breaking bugfix, but obviously something has changed. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you show a simple example reproducing the issue?  In a jsbin?

Comment: I have an example in [this](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/issue-with---nextsuper/5898/2) thread, along with a way to build the source. I'll try to create a smaller, more simple example this weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember 1.6 looks to have a requirement on super method being called from the scope of the object hosting the super method (probably a bug, but I'm not positive).  In your case you'd want to keep track of the scope, then call the super method using it:

(scope is the object that houses isEqual)

```
 var scope = meta.isEqual ? meta : this.get('store').attributeTypeFor(meta.type);
 if (scope.isEqual(server, value)) { ...
```

instead of (scope is window and explodes in 1.6+)

```
 var isEqual = meta.isEqual || this.get('store').attributeTypeFor(meta.type).isEqual;
 if (isEqual(server, value)) { ...
```

Here's a super simple example showing the problem (1.6+): http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yelesahe/1/edit

And working in 1.5.1: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zedevudo/1/edit

Issue: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/5198

Comment: I was gone this weekend, so I couldn't get around to making a better JSBin. Looks like you solved the issue anyway though. Thanks again.